# Regex to find Java collections declarations

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a Regex pattern to find java collections declarations.
Example: i want to match below lines

```
private List<String> test;
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> test1;
```

I am trying the Pattern

```
(private|public|protected) [A-Za-z]{1,}<([A-Za-z]* *\W*[A-Za-z]\W*)> *[A-za-z]*;
```

Comment: You can't parse Java with a regex, and no parser can identify whether `List` refers to `java.util.List` or something else.

Comment: Closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Comment: 1, If you are going to parse/validate _arbitrary infinite_ nested structures in collection declaration, [this is not possible using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns).  It may work _only_ with the fixed number of nested levels.  2. Please review the pattern of Java identifier -- it would fail even for your example because it does not include digits as well other valid characters.

Comment: Also, this will not only match declarations of collections, but all object declarations of generic types. And it will miss collections declared as rawtypes.

Comment: What something as simple as  `List|ArrayList|LinkedList|Set|TreeSet|HashSet|Map|TreeMap|HashMap` suffice?